# Get biggest COUNT(DISTINCT) with condition mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct, conditional-statements

right now I'm trying to return the biggest COUNT(DISTINCT column)-number from a mysql table.
It's hard to describe, so I'll give you an example:

My table has the following columns: s_id, k_id, p_id.
Now I want to count the different s with the condition that every entry has the same p_id, too. I need this to prepare a HTML-Table (so i know how many Columns this table will have).

**Data Example:**

[image: Data Sample]

This is what I got, so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT k_id) AS a FROM `table`
```

the problem with this is, that there may be 4 different k_ids but 3 of them are related to p_id = 1 and the last one is releated to p_id = 2.
a returns 4 instead of 3.

Thanks for support!

Comment: Show sample data and what you would expect the output to be

Comment: This is my current table content: [link](http://s16.postimg.org/cz02qn1g1/distinct.png)
The output is "4" but it should be "3", because the max distinct k_ids for a p_id is 3

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
  select p_id, count(distinct s_id) as cnt
  from table 
  group by p_id
  order by cnt desc
  limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this:

```
select max(count(distinct(k_id))) from table 
group by p_id
```

Comment: No, this would return 3 not 4 because of the grouping. However there seems that sql server doesn't allow to perform an aggregate function on an aggregate and hence max(count()) is not allowed

Comment: a way around is as follows : select max(cnt) from (
select count(distinct(k_id)) as cnt from table1 
group by p_id
) x

Comment: I think your second suggestion does the job! Right now it returns "3"! Thanks!

Comment: I can understand accepting an answer that seems to have nothing to do with the question.  I don't understand accepting an answer that is syntactically incorrect.